# java: module not found error - NXP TapLinx Sample App (IntelliJ/Maven)

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I am brand new to the Java/IntelliJ development environment. I am simply trying to get a sample app working which is included within the NXP TapLinx SDK (https://www.mifare.net/en/products/tools/taplinx/). When I try to build the sample app, I get the following errors:

```
C:\taplinx\sample_app\src\main\java\module-info.java:14:21
java: module not found: taplinx.librarymanager
C:\taplinx\sample_app\src\main\java\module-info.java:15:21
java: module not found: taplinx.ntag
```

The module-info.java file looks like this:

```
module NTagJavaSampleApp {
    requires java.smartcardio;
    requires javafx.graphics;
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires org.slf4j;
    requires java.desktop;
    requires java.prefs;
    requires com.google.common;
    requires ez.vcard;
    requires com.google.gson;
    exports com.sample.ntag;
    opens com.sample.ntag.controller to javafx.graphics, javafx.controls, javafx.fxml;
    requires taplinx.librarymanager;
    requires taplinx.ntag;
}
```

The SDK documentation has you download 2 zips, one is the sample application itself and the other are several libraries distributed as .JARs. You are instructed to open the project, create a "libs" folder and copy the jars to this folder. Then go to Project Structure -> Modules -> Dependencies and add the libraries. All this goes fine, however when I go to build the project I get the following errors:

This seemed pretty straight-forward so I'm not sure what I did wrong. I will mention that the documentation seems slightly out of date as it refers to the JAR files as being named "taplinx-ntag.jar" and "taplinx-librarymanager.jar", when they are in fact named "ntag-3.1.0-RELEASE.jar" and "librarymanager-3.1.0-RELEASE.jar".

I updated the pom.xml files to point to the correct JAR file names but that's the only deviation I've made from the docs. The pom.xml entries look like:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.nxp.nfclib.ntag</groupId>
    <artifactId>librarymanger</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version><scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${basedir}/libs/librarymanager-3.1.0-RELEASE.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.nxp.nfclib.ntag</groupId>
    <artifactId>ntag</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${basedir}/libs/ntag-3.1.0-RELEASE.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

I did run Maven -> Reload Project to no avail.. I've gone through this whole procedure twice now and come up with the same errors.  Any ideas?

Comment: A modular JAR file is a JAR file that contains a `module-info.class` file. Do the JAR files [`ntag-3.1.0-RELEASE.jar` and `librarymanager-3.1.0-RELEASE.jar`] contain a `module-info.class` file? If they do, then does that file declare a `taplinx.librarymanager` module and a `taplinx.ntag`? Note that if there is no `module-info.class` file in the JAR, IntelliJ will probably try to use the [Java] package name as the module name which means it will look for a `taplinx.librarymanager` package.

Answer (score 0):

There sample code has errors.
The docs, pom.xml and module-info.java have old jar names for taplinx.librarymanager and taplinx.ntag;

Changes:

```
module NTagJavaSampleApp {
...
requires librarymanager;
requires ntag;

Pom.xml

<dependency>
   <groupId>com.nxp.nfclib.ntag</groupId>
    <artifactId>librarymanger</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version><scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${basedir}/libs/librarymanager-3.1.0-RELEASE.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.nxp.nfclib.ntag</groupId>
   <artifactId>ntag</artifactId>
   <version>3.1.0</version>
      <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/libs/ntag-3.1.0-RELEASE.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```